# Django import error Point

Tags: django, gis, geospatial

I am working on gis project and I'm getting import error:
from django.contrib.gis.goes import Point

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000002D11840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 101, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 869, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\raut_s\PycharmProjects\Prototype\webMap\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
ImportError: cannot import name Point
```

I have django 1.6.5. Python is 3.3

Answer (score 5):

Try this on the command line

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS:

```
brew install libgeoip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at django/contrib/gis/geos/**init**.py, you can see the Point object is only available if HAS_GEOS is True, which depends on importing:

```
from .libgeos import geos_version, geos_version_info
```

So what fixed it for me was making sure all the geospatial dependencies are installed:

```
 sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
```

(As per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#geospatial-libs)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
I resolved the problem by installing libgeos and libgeos-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
```